# domain shows 403 Forbidden in browser console

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, browser, dns, console

I have configure my domain and SSL in AWS EC2 instance. When i write domain in browser, amazon test page has been loaded successfully but in browser console, it shows below error:

Request URL: https://xxxxx.com/
Request Method: GET
**Status Code: 403 Forbidden**
Remote Address: xx.xx.xx.xx:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Even when i test my domain in tools like "pingdom", it also display "403 Forbidden" in response code.
Can anyone provide solution to fix "403 Forbidden" issue?

Comment: can you explain how did you configure your website, please post some code and configurations

Comment: I have removed my website from this domain, right now just AWS test page is display. I am getting issue in AWS test page too. I have also remove SSL from my domain to check the issue. But still getting the same issue in console.

Answer (score 0):

This means your web server (apache, nginx ) https directory is different than HTTP

forbidden probably means you don't have index page in the www folder, for example, index.html, usually for the HTTP port there is a welcome page in the default configuration but not for https

Comment: I have removed SSL temporary, but still getting same issue.